# iframe height attribute not working with Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, iframe, height

My Firefox (version 3.6.17 on Ubuntu) is not responding to the `height` attribute of my iframe. (I checked that it works on my Google Chrome.)

```
<iframe src="www.example.com" width="100%" height="80%"></iframe>
```

or

```
<iframe src="www.example.com" width="100%" height="40%"></iframe>
```

How can I make it work?

If it's because my Firefox version is too old, how can I make it work for users who similarly have old version of Firefox?

Comment: Do all of its parents have the height attribute set?

Comment: @Bender It's parent is <body>, which has no height attribute set.

Comment: Try setting that to 100% for body and html.

Comment: @Bender Tried it, and unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have checked yout code in firefox 3.6 on OS X and this is working for me. To get it working I have added:

```
html, body { height:100%; } ​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XcdJ3/

However if you have iframe in some container, it must have also `height:100%` property.

Like in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/XcdJ3/2/

If you can't expand iframe with html and css try to do it in JavaScript, just take parent element height and apply it to iframe height tag.

Comment: Hmm I've added `height="100%"` to both the html and body HTML tags (which are all the parents), but it's still not working. Not sure why..

Comment: Add also height:100% to your css on all parents elements: html,body and container div.

Comment: Do the same if an object (iframe) is within a table. Ensure you add height:100% to the tbody as well